# Accessing Scala Variable: 'not found value: variable_name' Issue

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have two Scala Objects.

1. common_code
2. dependent_code

In common_code I have one method in which I am writing my common code and declaring some variables. I want to use these variables and code in my 2nd object but when I am trying to access these Varibales I'm getting common_method not found value: variable name issue.

I'm using below code.

```scala
object comman_code{
    def common_method(args: Array[String]) {
        val properties: Properties = new Properties()
        val hdfsConf = new Configuration();
        val fs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(hdfsConf);
        val is = fs.open(new Path(args(0)));
        properties.load(is)
        //created sparkSesssion

        //Table_Name i want to use in 2nd program
        val Table_Name = properties.getProperty("Table_Name") 
    }
}

object dependent_code {
    def main(args: Array[String]):Unit = {
        val common_method = helper_class.common_method(args)
        val mydf=sparksesssion.sql(s"select * from ${Table_Name}").show() //not able to acess getting not found value: Table_Name
    }
}
```

Can someone please suggest how I can access `Table_Name` variable in my other object?

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with Scala Objects they are instantiated automatically and you can easily access them like shown below.

```scala
object common_code {
    def common_method(args: Array[String]): String = {
        val properties: Properties = new Properties()
        val hdfsConf = new Configuration();
        val fs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(hdfsConf);
        val is = fs.open(new Path(args(0)));
        properties.load(is)
        //created sparksesssion
        val Table_Name: String = properties.getProperty("Table_Name")
        Table_Name
    }
}

object dependent_code {
    def main(args: Array[String]):Unit = {
        val tableName: String = common_code.common_method(args)
        val mydf=sparksesssion.sql(s"""select * from ${tableName}""").show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike I've tried this but its showing value Table_Name is not a member of Unit.

Comment: Sorry, was confused with the brackets. Make sure that `Table_Name` is the output of your `common_method`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike.I tried this code and its working. but if 1 have multiple  variable and want to use all how can i use those. i.e. val Table_Name2: String = properties.getProperty("Table_Name2").I tried using return type as properties but it's not giving desired result,giving values in {,} format.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing here is that you cannot access to fields which are located inside method.
You should not assign to a variable (val Table_Name) on the last line in `common_method`, but return it. Otherwise your method is just `Unit`, meaning that nothing will return after invoke. Here is little improvement that you can try understand:

```
object comman_code {
  def common_method(args: Array[String]): String = {
    val properties: Properties = new Properties()
    val hdfsConf = new Configuration();
    val fs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(hdfsConf);
    val is = fs.open(new Path(args(0)));
    properties.load(is)
    //created sparksesssion
    properties.getProperty("Table_Name")
  }
}

object dependent_code {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val tableName = comman_code.common_method(args)
    val mydf = sparksesssion.sql(s"select * from $tableName").show() 
  }
}
```

Note: I called `common_method` from `common_code` object and the result is assigned to a variable called `tableName`. Then in turn `tableName` is used in string interpolation.

Couple of another suggestions:

1. [Naming Conventions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html)
2. [How to post a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)